# Rails 3 - How to deal with complicated Switch Statements / If Statements

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm building a method that ingests incoming email, and processes the email. Along the way there are a lot of things that could prevent the email from being processes successfully. The wrong reply-to address, the wrong from address, an empty message body etc..

The code is full of Switch Statements (case/when/end) and If statements. I'd like to learn a smarter, cleaner way of doing this. Additionally, a way to can track an error and at the end have one location where it emails back the user with an error. Is something like this possible with rails?

```
@error = []

Case XXX
when xxxx
  if XXXXX
  else
   @error = 'You don't have permission to reply to the xxxxx'
  end
else
  @error = 'Unfamilar XXXX'
end
```

Then something at the end like...

```
If @errors.count > 0
   Send the user an email letting them know what went wrong
else
 do nothing
end
```

Thanks for the help here. If you know of any other tutorials that would teach me how to write logic like the above smarter, that'd be great. Right now I have case/if statements going 3 levels deeps, it's hard to keep it straight.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest using Exceptions. Start with [this tutorial](http://ruby.activeventure.com/programmingruby/book/tut_exceptions.html), then use Google, trial and error to go from there.

**Edit:** In more complex cases, exceptions may not be the right tool. You might want to use validator functions instead, for example (see other answers), or you could just return early instead of nesting ifs, e.g.:

```
unless sender_valid?
  @error = "Sender invalid"
  return
end
unless subject_valid?
  @error = "Invalid command"
  return
end
# normal no-errors flow continues here...
```

Comment: I highly prefer exceptions. The implicit exit from the method is exactly what you want in most cases.

Comment: Only use exceptions when you're dealing with a real exception. If it's an expected flow, than don't use exceptions. For instance: any data that the user entered will often be wrong and should never be handled with an exception. The real way to clean up your code is to divide it into small logical chunks (methods and classes). Having nested cases and ifs is usually a design issue. Using exceptions in this case is just a bandaid, but not the real solution.

Comment: If you have a complex case, it might be better to abstract things out into validator functions instead of using exceptions. Weigh your options.

Comment: Will Exceptions mess up delayed job?

Comment: Not if you catch (`rescue`) them.

Comment: Strange, i'm loving this by the way. I just implemented it, delayed_job is erroring and it seems like delayed_job some how surpresses the error. All I see is that delayed_jobs was updated with a failed attempt. It doesn't say in the logs why it failed.

Comment: Rails.logger.info doesnt seem to appear in the logs with delayed_job

Answer (score 3):

First, I would just assign a symbol to each error message as a simple hash:

```
ErrorsDescription = {
  :first => "First error",
  :second => "Second error",
  ...
}
```

And use symbols instead of strings.

Then, your if and switch statements. Basicaly I can't really help you, because I don't see what kind of condition statements you have. What are you checking? Why do you have 3 level deep conditions? Probably you can write it simpler using if and switch - so this is my first answer to this issue. Another solution may be writing simple methods to improve readability, so you can write like this:

```
if @email.has_wrong_reply_to_address? 
  @errors << :wrong_reply_to_address
else
  ...
end
```

Also, as @mpapis suggested, you can use Rails build in validation system, but not as `ActiveRecord` but as `ActiveModel`. [Here](http://yehudakatz.com/2010/01/10/activemodel-make-any-ruby-object-feel-like-activerecord/) you have some examples how to do it and how it works (also take a look [here](http://lindsaar.net/2010/1/31/validates_rails_3_awesome_is_true)). Of course you may need to write custom validations, but they are just simple methods. Once you do all above job, you can just use:

```
@email.valid?
```

And if it is not, you have all errors in hash:

```
@email.errors
```

Just as in ordinary `ActiveRecord` object.

Then you may extend your `Emial` class with `send_error_email` method which sends an email if there was an error.

EDIT:

This is about new information you attached in comment.

You don't have to use nested ifs and switch here. You can have it looking like this:

```
def is_this_email_valid?
  if !email_from_user_in_system?
    @errors << :user_not_in_system
    return false
  end
  if comment_not_exists?
    @errors << :comment_not_exists
    return false
  end
  if user_cannot_comment_here?
    @errors << :permision_error
    return false
  end
  ...
  true
end
```

Then you can use it:

```
if !@email.is_this_email_valid?
  @email.send_error_mail
end
```

Comment: thanks .The reason It goes 3 levels deep is. First I check to make sure the email came from a user in the system. Then I make sure they are replying to a comment that exists. Then I make sure they have permission to reply to that comment. Then I make sure the comment isn't blank/nil. Make sense?

Comment: @AnApprentice: yep, it makes sense. But why reply to a comment is through a mail? Can't you use html forms for this?

Comment: @AnApprentice: Why don't you just exit early? E.g. "if mail is not from valid user, return error".

Answer (score 1):

You could throw an error when something is not right.  Then catch it at the end of your method.

http://phrogz.net/programmingruby/tut_exceptions.html

To make your code more readable and not have a lot of switch and if/then statements, you could create separate methods that validate certain aspects and call them from your main error-checking method.

Comment: using exceptions might slow your application up to 17 times

Comment: @mpapis: are you sure it is true for Ruby? Can you give some references?

Comment: http://rpheath.com/posts/237-raising-custom-exceptions-in-rails - in the comments

Comment: If it's working on incoming mail, it is most likely an offline job anyway. But even if it wasn't, more readable code and easier error handling surely outweighs the "up to" 17x performance decrease, IMO.

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible to map your message to a model ? then all the if/switch logic would be validations and automatically handled by rails. Good starting point is [active record validations guide](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html)

Also worth reading is [action mailer guide](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html)